# One-to-one relationship Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core-2.0

I have two tables one with a list of clients and the other whether they are active or not. I want to link them Entity Framework, however, I am struggling. The two tables were already setup and have to primary keys or foreign keys.

```
namespace DataWarehouse.Models
{
    public class DatabaseList
    {
        [Key]
        public string STARDB { get; set; }
        public int DBClientID { get; set; }
        public string ClientName { get; set; }
        public DatabaseStatus DatabaseStatus { get; set; }

        public ICollection<PayComponents> PayComponents { get; set; }
         = new List<PayComponents>();
    }

    public class DatabaseStatus
    {
        [Key]
        public string STARDB { get; set; }
        public string STATUS { get; set; }

        public DatabaseList DatabaseList { get; set; }
    }

    public class DatabaseContext : DbContext
    {
        public DatabaseContext(DbContextOptions<DatabaseContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }

        public DbSet<DatabaseList> DatabaseList { get; set; }
        public DbSet<DatabaseStatus> Status { get; set; }
        public DbSet<PayComponents> PayComponents { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<DatabaseList>()
                .HasOne(p => p.DatabaseStatus)
                .WithOne(i => i.DatabaseList)
                .HasForeignKey<DatabaseStatus>(k => k.STARDB);
        }
    }
}
```

I was hoping that Entity Framework would see the columns `STARDB` and notice that it is the same in both tables and match them that way. All I want to is to add the `Status` column from `DatabaseStatus` into the `Databaselist` table.

Thanks.

Comment: You can also specify which field to use as a FK with the `ForeignKey` attribute. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships#data-annotations

Comment: Check this site, shows you how to setup a 1:1 in entity framework http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx

Comment: I think this link is what shows 1:1: http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-one-relationship-in-code-first.aspx

Comment: @L0uis thanks very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to figure it out. My database was setup properly. However, I forgot the include statement in my Repository.cs class.

```
    public IEnumerable<DatabaseList> GetAllClients()
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("Get all clients was called");

        var clients = _ctx.DatabaseList
                       .Include(d => d.DatabaseStatus)
                       .OrderBy(p => p.ClientName)
                       .ToList();

        return clients;
    }
```

Still new to C# so a bit of learning curve!